# How to scrobble to last.fm from YouTube played via Apple TV?

Tags: appletv, youtube, last.fm

I got some rad new sonos speakers and hooked them up to my TV. So naturally I'm now playing more music videos on YouTube. But Last.fm isn't picking up these scrobbles. Bummer!

What can I do to make sure I'm tracking these plays in Last.fm?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an app this won't help, but if you're just using a web browser I recently released [ScrobYou](https://scrobyou.com/). It lets you search for and watch music videos from YouTube and scrobbles what you watch all in one simple webpage